# CORS and the null origin

Tags: apache, cors

I have a case where im getting a null returned from a header returned form a CAS server of null

to get over this I added

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin null
```

so now I have

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin null
```

but now I get objections when i return a non null origin header 
how can I have both in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

is there a way to OR them???

sorry forgot to mention this is in my httpd.conf for the apache server

tried this as well

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin null
```

actually further investigation reveals

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin null
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://accp.oursite.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://wwwtest.oursite.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.oursite.com"
```

does seem to add to that header not sure if its usable though

and in the response headers I see

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin :"*, null, https://accp.oursite.com, http://wwwtest.oursite.com, http://www.oursite.com"
```

Comment: About your update, you can’t have multiple values in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. It needs to be a single value—either a URL, `*`, or `null`.

Comment: oh ok I started off with * but then when the one site returns null * didnt cover it ...so am I out of luck?

Comment: Typically what most configurations do is: Take the value of the `Origin` header from the request, and echo it in the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response. So if the request has `Origin: null`, then the response will have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null`, and if the request has `Origin: http://example.com`, the response will have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com`.

Comment: ok I will try that ...the server giving me the issue is a CAS server used for SSO authentication Ill see if it works with it thanks SSB